# libshadow-ruby1.8 removed in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, chef-infra, apt

I've got chef cookbook that uses libshadow-ruby1.8 for password hashing. Kitchen test passes using ubuntu 12.04 but I'm getting this error on 14.04

```
ERROR: apt_package[libshadow-ruby1.8] (its-3D::sftp line 8) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Package: No candidate version available for libshadow-ruby1.8
```

I'm wondering if the package got removed if so why.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libshadow-ruby/+question/274058

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libshadow-ruby/+changelog

I asked the same question on the ubuntu answers and got a good response.